# Hyundai i20 1.4 glide 2012 model

Tags: fuel-system, rpm

Evening guys, my car  has a very serious problem, it consumes too much fuel and i have noticed that my rev counter is very high when driving, if am driving 100km\h the rev counter would be at 4100rpm, if am driving 120km\h it would be around 4500rpm, 140 its around 5000rpm and that consumes too much fuel,i visited some mechanics and they dont seem to know what the problem is..Help please I am in polokwane

Answer (score 0):

If it is a manual transmission, the clutch is worn out and about to fail and leave you stranded, get it replaced.

If it is an automatic the transmission is failing and may leave you stranded, get it rebuilt or replaced.